# What year does Cable come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

It's far enough in the future that he can travel through time, but

> not too far because Rusty's still alive to kill Cable's family

Comment: I THINK he says in the film that he's planning to go back to his own time, which is 50 years in the future, but I don't remember with enough certainty to make that an answer...

Comment: @Dave - That's what I remember as well.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Having rewatched the scene now, it's not a confirmation.  DP states "Betcha 50 years from now we're bestest buddies" but Cable replies "50 years from now you're dead.  Your entire generation f**ked this planet into a coma."

Comment: In that Cameo, we see cyclops in the room. Cable is cyclops' kid from the future. This cable looks 50 years old (Brolin's age). If Cyclops and Jean got it "on" in a couple of years, we can say that Cable is about 52-54 years from the future.

Answer (score 1):

His future is most likely set in **2068**.

Cable quotes

> "50 years from now, you're very dead. Your entire generation fucked this planet into a coma."

Deadpool 2 takes place in 2018, 50 years from that is 2068.

Answer (score -2):

On this website here: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Nathan_Summers_(Earth-616)

It says that he is sent to the late 37th or early 39th century, because he was infected with the Techno-Organic Virus.

But on this other website: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/cable/4005-2157/

It just says that he was sent 2000 years into the future to survive the Virus.

His Wiki Article says that he was born in the **Year 1986**.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_(comics)

By doing some simple Math, my guess would be that he spent his early life in the **40th Century** or the **Year 3986**.

Please note that i am no expert in Marvel Lore.

Comment: I don't have an answer but this one is wrong as Rusty doesn't seem to be able to survive nearly 2000 years

Comment: The comics timeline is very different from the movies, at least for the MCU, my guess is that it is also different in Deadpool, seems like he is about 50 years in the future for this movie.